# re-arranging array elements so get maximum sum

Tags: arrays

I have an array whose length is exactly divisible by 3 and the elements are all in descending order. If we group the array elements by 3 and take the sum of it i should get the maximum values.

For example,
int[] input={9,8,7,6,5,4}

Now if we group the array elements 987 and 654 we get a sum of 1641.

I have to rearrange the elements such that i get the maximum sum.

So the output array must be as follows:
int[] output={9,7,5,8,6,4}

Now if we group the array elements 975 and 864 we get a sum of 1839.

I tried it but unable to get it can anybody help me out with the logic.

Comment: What did you try? What worked? What didn't?

Comment: I used this code but its not working.

Comment: for (i = 0; i<n/2 ;i++)
{       if (i == 0)
          {
              op[i] = arr[i];
                    op[small] = arr[small];
                }
                else
                {
                    op[mid] = arr[i];
                    op[mid - 1] = arr[mid - 1];
                    mid++;
                }
            }

Comment: Have you solved it eventually?

Answer (score 0):

I've written it in Python3. The point is in the most uniform number distribution possible.

```
inpArr = [5,2,8,4,9,6,7,1,3]

sortedInpArr = sorted(inpArr, reverse=True)
print(sortedInpArr)

buffNum = int(len(sortedInpArr) / 3)

for n in range(0, buffNum):
    for i in range(0, len(sortedInpArr)):
        if i % buffNum == n:
            print(sortedInpArr[i], end="")
    print() # new line
```